# Simple Syntax Error in SQLite: "Error near line 1: near "SQLite"

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am having a great deal of trouble with this seemingly simple issue. I can't seem to get .read to work. Here is the code that I have tried: 
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.open test.sql
```

This opens a Sqlite3 database (Creating a new one if the file doesn't already exist) and attaches it as the main one in the sqlite3 shell session.

```
.read test.sql
```

This attempts to read a text file full of SQL statements and execute them one by one.

A sqlite database is *not* a text file full of SQL statements, hence the syntax errors when you try to treat it as one.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
CREATE TABLE t (x int);
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE t (x INTEGER);
```

Read more about the [CREATE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) statement and [data types](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: Even with the correct syntax, I still receive the "SQLite" syntax error.

Comment: On which statement?

Comment: On the statement .read test.sql, which outputs "Error: near line 1..." as shown in the picture in the post.

Comment: Then post 'test.sql'. There must be a syntax error in it.

Comment: 'test.sql' is originally empty. If you look at the code above, everything in test.sql is described there and with the corrected line of CREATE TABLE t (x int);